# How can I get the browser's screen height?

Tags: cgi, height, screen

Does anyone know how to get the screen height in a Perl CGI script? I know that Perl is a server-side language but is there any way to get the screen height (pixels) of the users screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean getting the height of the user's browser window?

There's no way to get that information without using some Javascript.

I would use Javascript/CSS to control presentation (like width and height), not the backend language.

Comment: Yes I want to get the height of the user's window. I guessed that JavaScript was the solution although I didn't know if Perl could handle that. I'll try with the screen.height of JavaScript 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

well, you can use js to set a cookie of the height
then in next request, use Perl CGI to get the cookie.

do remember, you will not get the height in the first visit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading up this
[Howtocreate article](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow)

There are different interpretations of a window height/width, and you should know these quirks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure , make an ajax request with either XMLHttpRequest or jQuery (or whatever other framework you prefer) and send window.innerHeight to your server